# JavaScript post request to Google cloud functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, google-cloud-platform, cors

I need to make a POST call with a JSON from JavaScript to a web server in cloud functions (GCP)

```js
$.ajax({
        url: "https://europe-west6-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/Translate_V2",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "application/json",
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        mode: "no-cors",
        header:`{
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS",
            "Origin":"*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With"
        }`,
        data: `{
            "lingua_in": "it",
            "lingua_out":"en",
            "audio": ${mybase64datatruncate}
        }`,
        success: changeTranslate,
        error: ajaxFailed
    });
```

The cloud function works, in fact making a post call from a website does not have problems, but making the call from local with or without apache I have the following errors:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs9pe.png)

The call arrives at the cloud functions but the JSON seems to arrive empty or is blocked because the function crashes, while in the post call from a website the call does not crash and returns a correct result.

I also installed Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the result doesn't change

Comment: I don't see any Python here: is there a reason your question needs the Python tag?

Comment: A list of errors in your question is better than a link to an image of those errors. Having the text allows them to be searched. Otherwise, this is a good question.

Comment: Google about CORS, you don't understand how it works

Comment: [Please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=DO%20NOT%20post%20images%20of%20code%2C%20data%2C%20error%20messages%2C%20etc.)

Comment: Are you using authentication on your function? In your `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, I can see you're allowing the header `Authorization`, which would only be required if the function is non-public.